# UserControl - set value to property

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, remote-debugging, design-time

I'm trying to design my custom `UserControl` for `WinForms` applications. I used to create customized enum property that works perfect and creates one `CheckBox` when user change property value in design-time.

```
    private SearchOptionsEnum _searchAreas;
    //private List<bool> _searchAreas = new List<bool>();
    [Description(""), Category("GostcompSettings")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(Utils.FlagEnumUIEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public SearchOptionsEnum SearchAreas
    //public List<bool> SearchAreas
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchAreas;
        }
        set
        {

            _searchAreasChceckBoxList.Clear();
            pPanelWithCheckboxies.Controls.Clear();
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;

            CheckBox _tempCheck = new CheckBox();
            _tempCheck.Checked = true;
            _tempCheck.Location = new Point(x, y);

            _searchAreasChceckBoxList.Add(_tempCheck);
            pPanelWithCheckboxies.Controls.Add(_tempCheck);

            MessageBox.Show("zmiana");
            _searchAreas = value;
        }
    }
```

I am using custom value editor [UITypeEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13793/A-UITypeEditor-for-easy-editing-of-flag-enum-prope) in the code and it works fine.

I get MessageBox in Design-Time and CheckBox appears. Problem is when I change SearchOptionsEnum to `List<bool>` and editor to default `Boolean Collection Editor`.

Then the CheckBox does not appear, and even debbuger breakpoint put in the set property does not stop there...

Where is the problem?

Moreover: When I edit bool values in editor it memorize it and keeps values. Even in next debugging session values set before are kept.

EDIT

```
public partial class StudySearchAndView : UserControl
{
    private List<CheckBox> _searchAreasChceckBoxList = new List<CheckBox>();

    private SearchOptionsEnum _searchAreas;
    //private List<bool> _searchAreas = new List<bool>();
    [Description(""), Category("GostcompSettings")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(Utils.FlagEnumUIEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public SearchOptionsEnum SearchAreas
    //public List<bool> SearchAreas
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchAreas;
        }
        set
        {

            _searchAreasChceckBoxList.Clear();
            pPanelWithCheckboxies.Controls.Clear();
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;

            CheckBox _tempCheck = new CheckBox();
            _tempCheck.Checked = true;
            _tempCheck.Location = new Point(x, y);

            _searchAreasChceckBoxList.Add(_tempCheck);
            pPanelWithCheckboxies.Controls.Add(_tempCheck);

            MessageBox.Show("zmiana");
            _searchAreas = value;
        }
    }

}
```

`pPanelWithCheckboxies` is just a panel dropped on UserControl.

Comment: Can you show more code for better understanding?

Comment: I'll try the BooleanCollectionEditor of UITypeEditor later, maybe some bugs there (I guess). However, if you edit some value in property page of design mode, it used to be memorize by writing those value to `InitializeComponent()` method. Or do I misunderstanding your last paragraph?

Comment: @J.C yes like you saying

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki If so, those values will be kept for different sessions, just like you change the properties of standard controls (such as label, textbox)

Comment: It's not the case here

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki If not, I need more detail about your "Moreover" paragraph. BTW, please tag me when you add a comment, or I may miss your new comments.

Answer (score 0):

Controls appear only if Parent is set. You should set the Parent of _tempCheck to this.

```
        CheckBox _tempCheck = new CheckBox();
        _tempCheck.Parent = this;
        _tempCheck.Checked = true;
        _tempCheck.Location = new Point(x, y);
```